# Upload file Yii The second argument to copy() function cannot be a directory

Tags: upload, yii, directory, lampp

I'm trying to upload file but get this error message :

```
 move_uploaded_file() [<a href='function.move-uploaded-file'>function.move-uploaded-file</a>]: The second argument to copy() function cannot be a directory
```

I think there's something problem with this file but I've no idea to solve it..

```
    <?php


    class FileUploadController extends CController {


    public function actionUpload() {
        $model = new FileUpload();
    $form = new CForm('application.views.fileUpload.uploadForm', $model);
        if ($form->submitted('submit') && $form->validate()) {
            $form->model->image = CUploadedFile::getInstance($form->model, 'image');


                  if($model->validate())
            {
                $model->image->saveAs('/opt/lampp/htdocs/upl/images');

            Yii::app()->user->setFlash('success', 'File Uploaded');
            $this->redirect(array('upload'));
            }


        }
        $this->render('upload', array('form' => $form));
    }
}

?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You either need to check all files existed at `'/opt/lampp/htdocs/upl/images'` and check if the same named file is available or not, if available then just rename the file with extra "_1" every time, or you can always upload the file by renaming the file into some machine name sort of thing see the code below,

```
$name = rand(1000,9999) . time(); // rand(1000,9999) optional
$name = md5($name); //optional
$model->image->saveAs('/opt/lampp/htdocs/upl/images/' . $name . '.jpg');
```

This is what I usually do with file uploads, provided that you're saving the files references into the database or in any text file.

EDIT

**Get Extension.**

In case if you're required to get extension of the file rather then of hard-coded, you can use `$model->image->getExtensionName();` it will get you the extension of the uploaded file without `.` (dot)

Comment: please tell me how to add $name to my database model, because the $model->image real name is the previous name of my image with any md5 code.how add md5 code to the  $model->image  ?

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I solved it by myself:

The problem was located in line

```
$model->image->saveAs('/opt/lampp/htdocs/upl/images');
```

It should be :

```
$model->image->saveAs('/opt/lampp/htdocs/upl/images/images.jpg');
```

Now, there's another problem: when I upload 'new image', it will be replace the old file, I want the file(s) being uploaded not replaced the old file or I need something like rename as new file. Does anyone knows?

Comment: If you have another problem, ask a separate question, or edit your existing question if the original problem still needs work. Don't ask questions inside answers: they will not be seen nearly as widely and can't be properly replied to.

Answer (score 0):

goto cuploadedfile.php .
over write this function with this

```
if($this->_error==UPLOAD_ERR_OK)
{
    if($deleteTempFile)
        return move_uploaded_file($this->_tempName,$file."/".$this->getName());
    elseif(is_uploaded_file($this->_tempName))
        return copy($this->_tempName, $file."/".$this->getName());
    else
        return false;
}
```

thank u.........